# Google Closure: goog.require in Play 2.2.1

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0, google-closure-compiler

I've been beginning a new Play project using Play v2.2.1 and am having difficulty getting the Google Closure compiler to properly handle goog.provide and goog.require statements. All of my Javascript files are in the app/assets folder and are being served up properly using Play's reverse routing. However, any time I try to use `goog.require(_namespace_)`, I get the compilation error "required *namespace* namespace not provided yet." This happens whether I link to just the file with the require or both the requiring and providing .js files in my view template. However, it does not happen if I link to the minified version of the requiring file.

For the most part, the closure compiler seems to be working; for example, the .min.js files do exist (even if they don't actually seem to be getting minified, but that is probably a separate issue). I haven't changed any build settings in my Play project.

The [Play documentation on using the Google Closure compiler](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/AssetsGoogleClosureCompiler) for Play 2.2.x does not directly reference using `goog.require()` and `goog.provide()` for Javascript dependencies. It does, however, give a link to using RequireJS to do the job. Is there no way to take advantage of the Closure compiler's require system?

As a disclaimer, I am not very experienced with the Closure compiler. I have used it at work where we minify all of our Javascript to one file, so all I know is basically what result I expect to see. I was hoping Play would have taken care of most of the dirty work of making everything "just work", but it doesn't seem as straightforward as I'd hoped and I haven't had any success solving the problem after a few hours of scouring the web.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plovr plugin that Benn McCann did based on some stuff I posted on the play mailing list a long time ago, which from what I remember was created because of this exact problem, maybe you could use that: https://github.com/benmccann/play-plovr-plugin

Comment: This looks very promising. I haven't heard of Plovr before, but it sounds like a helpful tool. I'll give this plugin a try. However, I'm still hoping to find a solution that uses just Play 2.2's Closure support without having to worry about any plugins.